# NHibernate linq fetch query across multiple joins with subquery causes incorrect sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, nhibernate

I have four tables in a sql server databases:

```
Part
-----
Id (PK)
LineId (FK)
other fields...

Line
-----
Id (PK)
ProcessId (FK)
other fields...

Process
-----
Id (PK)
ProcessTypeId (FK)
other fields...

ProcessType
-----
Id (PK)
other fields...
```

I am trying to use a linq query with fetch to hydrate these entities then map the result to a view model dto.

I am using two queries, one is on `Part`, I am applying a filter on it to narrow down the result:

```
var partids = s.Query<Part>()
               .Where(p => p.Line.Process.ProcessType.Id == processTypeId)
               .Select(p => p.Id);
```

I then use this query to eager load the related entities and use the first query as a subquery:

```
var q = s.Query<Part>()
         .Fetch(p => p.Line)
         .ThenFetch(l => l.Process)
         .ThenFetch(pr => pr.ProcessType)
         .Where(p => partids.Contains(p.Id))
         .ToList();
```

Though this query works, I noticed that was taking a very long time to load. So,  using a profiler, I looked at the generated SQL which was:

```
SELECT part0_.Id AS Id0_0_,
       line1_.Id AS Id1_1_,
       process2_.Id AS Id2_2_,
       process3_.Id AS Id3_3_,
       part0_.Name AS Name0_0_,
       part0_.LineId AS Line3_0_0_,
       line1_.Name AS Name1_1_,
       line1_.ProcessId AS Proccess3_1_1_,
       process2_.Name AS Name2_2_,
       process2_.ProcessTypeId AS Proccess3_2_2_,
       process3_.Name AS Name3_3_
FROM part part0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN Line line1_ ON part0_.LineId=line1_.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Process process2_ ON line1_.ProcessId=process2_.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProcessType process3_ ON process2_.ProcessTypeId=process3_.Id
WHERE part0_.Id IN
    ( SELECT part4_.Id
     FROM Part Part4_
     INNER JOIN Line Line5_ ON Part4_.LineId=Line5_.Id
     WHERE process2_.ProcessTypeId= 126 );
```

Th subquery joining back onto the main query is causing this to run extremely slow in most cases.

I would have expected the generated SQL to be this:

```
SELECT part0_.Id AS Id0_0_,
       line1_.Id AS Id1_1_,
       process2_.Id AS Id2_2_,
       process3_.Id AS Id3_3_,
       part0_.Name AS Name0_0_,
       part0_.LineId AS Line3_0_0_,
       line1_.Name AS Name1_1_,
       line1_.ProcessId AS Proccess3_1_1_,
       process2_.Name AS Name2_2_,
       process2_.ProcessTypeId AS Proccess3_2_2_,
       process3_.Name AS Name3_3_
FROM part part0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN Line line1_ ON part0_.LineId=line1_.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Process process2_ ON line1_.ProcessId=process2_.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ProcessType process3_ ON process2_.ProcessTypeId=process3_.Id
WHERE part0_.Id IN
    ( SELECT part4_.Id
     FROM Part part4_
     INNER JOIN Line Line5_ ON part4_.LineId=Line5_.Id
     INNER JOIN Process Process6_ ON Line5_.LineId=Process6_.Id
     WHERE Process6_.ProcessTypeId= 126 );
```

I am using NHibernate 4 with the linq provider for all of my queries. Am I missing something in my linq query here?

The work around I use at the moment is to hydrate the `partids` query with `ToList` and then use the list of ids from memory. However, I would like to avoid two round trips to the database in this scenario if possible.

It is not currently feasible for me to use the `QueryOver` or `HQL` apis because all of my querying a filter code uses linq.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think the workaround that you're currently using is your best option.

This is a bug in NHibernate, it currently affects version 4 and I'm pretty sure it was there in 3.3 too.

The bug has been [reported](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3622).